# взаимозависимые чекбоксы

Tags: jquery

Для следующей верстки

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxsub1" class="main">
    <label for="checkboxsub1">
        Критерий
    </label>
    <div class="checkbox sub">
        <input type="checkbox" id="subcheckbox1" class="sub">
        <label for="subcheckbox1">
            Этот критерий не важен
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии внутреннего чекбокса, внешний становился `disablеd`.

```
$("input[type='checkbox'].sub ").change(function() {
    var box = $(this).parent().prevAll(".main");

    if($(this).checked) {
        box.attr('disabled', true)
    } else {
        box.attr('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

js выше не работает. Eсли сократить до:

```
$("input[type='checkbox'].sub ").change(function(){
var box = $(this).parent().prevAll(".main").attr("attr",true);
```

то атрибут добавляется. Но только не в том случае, если в качестве атрибута указано `"disabled"`.

Проблемы две:

1. не считывается `checkеd` при смене состояния чекбокса
2. не присваивается конкретно `disablеd` (prop тоже не решает проблемы)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так ? http://jsfiddle.net/v0ak67fe/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sub:checkbox ").change(function(){
        var box = $(this).parent().prevAll(".main");
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            box.attr('disabled', 'disabled')
        }
        else{
            box.removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });})
```

Comment: С учётом коммента @user3541422 - 
http://jsfiddle.net/v0ak67fe/2/

Comment: Да, то что надо, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Можно чуть проще: https://jsfiddle.net/v0ak67fe/1/

```
$('#checkboxsub1').attr('disabled', $(this).is(':checked') ? true: false);
```

Comment: но красивей, и как по мне правильней: $('#checkboxsub1').prop('disabled', $(this).prop('checked'));

Comment: @myvzar "disabled" - является атрибутом а не свойством. Следовательно использовать надо .attr() а не .prop() http://javascript.ru/tutorial/dom/attributes

Comment: @xFloooo Вы наверное не совсем хорошо читали документацию:`The .prop() method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr() method`  http://api.jquery.com/prop/